# Allocating void pointer from a template

Tags: c++, string, templates, pointers, void

I'm trying to do something like this in my `Obj` class:

```
public:
    template <typename T>
    Obj(T & o) {
        siz = sizeof(o);

        p = malloc(siz);
        memcpy(p, &o, siz);
    }   
private:                                
    void * p;
    size_t siz;
```

That works fine if i do something like this:

```
string str = "foobar";
Obj u = Obj(str);
```

but not if I do something like this:

```
Obj u = Obj(string("foobar"));
```

That results in a string filled with random characters.

To retreive the string I use:

```
string S() {
    return *((string *)p);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: _I'm trying to do something like this_  Why are you trying to do it this way? Whatever it is you are trying to do, there is probably a better way.

Comment: Every line of this code looks like a horrible nightmare. What are you *really* trying to achieve?

Comment: tip: memcpy does not belong in C++ code

Comment: Nor does `malloc`. Also storing things as `void *` is a bad idea. Lose the ability for the compiler to make things type safe.

Comment: This is indeed an abomination, @EdHeal, for both type-safety and the assumption T has no identity. I can have two 5s and they are the same, but they are each a different 5 @ op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented you should not be doing something like this. The code example you have given will not work for anything that is not a POD (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c). When you do the memcpy you may not be initializing the new object correctly. E.g. if it has members that are pointers. In the case of the string its implementation likely holds a pointer to a character buffer that is owned by the original string. When the original string gets deleted, the character buffer will too. But your memcopied object will still point to the deleted buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's extremely hard to guess what you are trying to do.

What you seem to be doing is making a binary copy of an object, which is a severe case of everything that is bad and evil. In your first case, you are doing this to a "real" object, so it might appear to work since the original object (the str object) is still around, so whatever pointer the copy contains still points to 'valid' data. In the second case, you are doing it to a temporary object which gets deallocated right after the thing, which is probably why your "copy" only has garbage.

Either way, from the looks of it, neither of the two actually do anything reaosnable at all. I'd say that your first example only appears to work.